# How to handle killed activity while loading an image

Tags: android, android-activity, background

I got a crash report that I'm not really sure how to handle: basically, a task that runs in the background crashes when it tries to use an attribute of the activity that launched it, because the attribute is null by the time it is called.

Here's the context. I have an ArticleActivity where the user can set the cover from his device library or from a new picture.

On result, I handle the data in the background as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode && RESULT_OK == resultCode) {
        App.doInBackground(this, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (data != null) {
                    try {
                        mArticle.setCover(Asset.createFromIntent(data)); // Crashes here
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // …
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // …
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Picasso.with(ArticleActivity.this).load(mArticle.getCoverBitmapFile()).into(mCoverImageView);
            }
        }, true);
    } else if (…) {
        …
    }
}
```

The doInBackground is pretty straightforward.

```
public static void doInBackground(final Activity activity, final Runnable background, final Runnable post, final boolean showProgress) {
    if (showProgress) {
        App.showProgressAction(activity);
    }
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            background.run();
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    post.run();
                    if (showProgress) {
                        App.hideProgressAction(activity);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

and Asset.createFromIntent(data) obviously creates a new entry in the db from the picker data and is pretty resource intensive.

So I assume the flow is as follows:

1. User launches the picker activity and selects a picture
2. onActivityResult is called, at this point mArticle is not null
3. Asset.createFromIntent(data) starts running in the background
4. For some reason, the ArticleActivity is killed, probably related to Asset.createFromIntent asking for too much resource, or maybe the user deleted the article or quit the app while the cover was loading
5. Asset.createFromIntent returns, but at this point, mArticle is null -> setCover crashes with a NullPointerException

Do you see any other flow that could lead to this crash?

Solutions I thought of:

- just check for mArticle != null and ignore setCover (really bad from a user point of view)
- create a local var with the Article id before calling Asset.createFromIntent and attempt to re-load the Article it if it's null

I'm not super familiar with the way onResume should be used (understand: I don't use it, I load mArticle onCreate), but from what I understood if mArticle is null because the activity was killed, onCreate will be called anyway.

So there it is, could I be missing something or should I just go with my 2nd solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main flaw about this approach is you're still trying to use the Activity's attributes, even though the activity is gone. I would recommend looking into using [IntentServices](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for background processing, and reporting the result back to the UI thread (Activity/Fragment)  using a [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html). In this approach, you would only be listening to the result of the background processing if your view instance is in the foreground, provided that you register and unregister correctly in the view's onResume() and onPause() respectively, this way you would avoid the scenario of trying to access the view's attributes after it's gone. Moreover, moving the background work to an IntentService would prevent it from being interrupted because of the activity's lifecycle events.

Looking into this [example](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html) would help getting the full image.

Comment: Ok, so this doesn't entirely solve the issue, I had to play with onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState as well but since it put me on the right path, I accepted it